# Do unused Cocoa Touch frameworks get included in the final build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have bunch of frameworks included in my XCode project.

I'm wondering what happens when I have these frameworks on the project but never `#import` them or use them. Do they get excluded from the final binary? Or are they still included even though I never call them?

Basically I'm wondering if I should go through and remove these frameworks whenever I don't need them (My current approach is to simply NOT include them, assuming they would be automatically excluded from the build if I never import/use/call them anywhere in the code. But suddenly just became curious if I'm mistaken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Doubt, answer is YES or TRUE ;)
All libraries, frameworks and lib files you add to project are get included in build you create.

Go to `TARGET -> SELECT YOUR TARGET -> Build Phases` then you can see multiple files and frameworks under `Compile Sources`, `Link Binary With Libraries` and `Copy Bundle Resources`, those all are responsible in increasing your build size as they are part of final build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all added libs or frameworks are included in final build.

If you are not using it at all you should remove it manually to exclude it otherwise final binary or build take it into count and your build size will increase.